# Convert from list to string in C#

Tags: c#, json

Before that I try to ask, i searched through the net but could not find what I am looking for.

I am trying to convert the field_values into string in C#.

type of fields_value :

```
public List<List<string>> field_values { get; set; }
```

this is my code that I want to modify it to do my work.

```
string x = pi.field_values[0];
```

I tried to do it with code below that does not work.

```
string x=convert.tostring(pi.field_values[0]);
```

any idea?

Comment: Please provide a sample of data and the desired result. At least I don't understand what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: And convert *how*? You have a list of lists of strings. So with `[0]` you access the first list of strings, not a single string.

Comment: `pi.field_values[0][0].ToString()`

Comment: in following json format,I want to retrieve the id and then compare it with an string   {
      "context": "65071",
      "names": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "hash",
        "score",
        "rank"
      ],
      "values": [
        [
          "187126",
          "187126",
          "187126",
          "0.1",
          "92.7157"
        ],
        [
          "494579",
          "494579",
          "494579",
          "0.05",
          "77.6358"
        ],
        [
          "455577",
          "455577",
          "455577",
          "0.0488174",
          "76.4856"
        ]...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`field_values[0]` is a `List<string>` not a `string`.

```
List<string> firstFieldValues = p.field_values[0];
```

You could for example use `String.Join` to concat multiple strings:

```
string allValues = string.Join(",", firstFieldValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get strings from the first list:

```
var str = field_values.ElementAt(0).Aggregate((aggr, next) => aggr + ", " + next);
```

or from all lists:

```
var allStr = field_values.SelectMany(l => l).Aggregate((aggr, next) => aggr + ", " + next);
```

Answer (score 0):

`field_values[0]` is a `List<string`> ... so you have to go through those lists and save them in a string:

```
string allStrings = "";
foreach (var li in field_values){
    foreach (var str in li){
        allStrings += str;
    }
}
```

Then you'll have all fields in one long string.