# List<string> into string and "argument out of range exception was unhandled" error

Tags: c#, json

When I try to compare a value from a `DataRow` with a json-string i get following error:

> argument out of range exception was unhandled.(Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index)

`uid` and `tid` are integers which are extracted from `DataSet` table:

```
int uid=0;
int tid=0;
int counter = 0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{ 
    string url = "aewrf/<uid>?groups=<uid>";
    var test = url.Replace("<uid>", Convert.ToString(row[uid]));
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(test); 
    string client = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(test); 
    var pi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<read_json>(client); 
    List<string> id = pi.field_values[0]; //error happens at this line
    string ids = Convert.ToString(id); 
    if (ids == Convert.ToString(row[tid])) 
    { 
        counter++; 
    } 
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: your code is not so much sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: @user3280040, what are you trying to achieve here: `string ids = Convert.ToString(id);`? Because now you try to convert `List<string>` into `string`, hence your error.

Comment: Why have you used `Convert.ToString(id)` on the list at all? In your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21626244/284240) i showed that you can use `string.Join(",", id)` to get a string. What was the problem? Do you want a single ID or loop all ID's instead?

Comment: I only want to extract the id from the list and compare it with a number(int) which i extracted from table. @TimSchmelter

Comment: @user3280040: i have edited your question to show the code. So you can delete that comment. In general post code in your question, otherwise it's not readable and also not visible on the first sight.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to length of array row is less than the value of tid.

change the if condition to overcome this exception as:

```
if (ids == Convert.ToString(row.Length>tid?row[tid]:""))
```

Comment: Are you sure about this command,@MaheshChand ? what do you mean by    (row.Length>tid?row[tid]:"")

Comment: @user3280040 I think its called a ternary command, but essentially shortform for if row.length is greater than tid, then row[tid], else ""

Answer (score 0):

Take this as an example

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    List<int> safePrimes = new List<int>(); // Create list of ints
    safePrimes.Add(5); // Element 1
    safePrimes.Add(7); // Element 2
    safePrimes.Add(11); // Element 3
    safePrimes.Add(23); // Element 4

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (int safePrime in safePrimes)
    {
        // Append each int to the StringBuilder overload.
        builder.Append(safePrime).Append(" ");
    }
    string result = builder.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Output

> 5 7 11 23

Reference [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/convert-list-string)

Answer (score 0):

Not answering your actual question and perhaps being a little pernickety I would form your url with String.Format - and outside of your foreach.  It seems inefficient to recreate the string each time and use replace.

```
string urlFormat = @"aewrf/{0}?groups={0}";

foreach (var row in x)
{
    string url = String.Format(urlFormat, Convert.ToString(row[uid]));
}
```